# How to update/Edit table through CSVs?

Tags: sql-server-2008, csv, stored-procedures

I stored 2 contact numbers in a table corresponding to one companyID in companycontactno. table. I did that using extracting values from CSV in Stored procedure.

If I want to edit those contact numbers Corresponding to company ID how am I going to do that?

This is the storedProcedure I will use for editing contact numbers .. I am having difficulty in updating it .. please help

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.EditCompanyDetails
(
@OldCompanyName varchar(max),
@NewCompanyName varchar(max),
@newAddress varchar(max),
@newMailID varchar(max),
@Temp varchar(8000)
)

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @compID int

DECLARE @c int, @a varchar(max), @id int, @variable varchar(8000), @max int

DECLARE @Temp_Table table (serial_no int Identity(1,1), value varchar(max))

--PROCEDURE--

--Editing Company Table--
set @compID=(Select Company.CompanyID from Company where Company.CompanyName=@OldCompanyName)

update Company
set CompanyName=@NewCompanyName, [Address]=@newAddress, Email=@newMailID
where Company.CompanyID=@compID

--For CONTACT NUMBERS

    --Using Table to store CSV seperately in each row--
select @c = CHARINDEX(',', @Temp)

while @c > 0
BEGIN
    insert into @Temp_Table
    select LEFT(@Temp, @c - 1)

    select @Temp = right(@Temp, LEN(@Temp) - @c)
    select @c = CHARINDEX(',', @Temp)
END

--Update Table CompanyContactNo
  --CompanyContactNo have following Columns:
   --CNoID (PK)
   --CompanyID (references PK in Company table
   --ContactNumber

set @max= (select MAX(serial_no) from @Temp_Table)


while @max > 0
BEGIN
set @variable = (select value from @Temp_Table where serial_no=@max)

update CompanyContactNo
set ContactNumber=@variable
where CompanyID=@compID
set @max = @max-1
END

End

GO
```

Comment: "update CompanyContactNo set ContactNumber=@variable where CompanyID=@compID"                                                      I know this is incorrect as it will save same contact number corresponding to the company id ..

Comment: If you have 2 contact numbers, which one do you want to use to update CompanyContactNo?  I wasn't sure from your code.

Comment: at PaulStock: i want to update my table CompanyContactNo which is storing 2 contact numbers corresponding one company ID ..

Comment: Are both contact numbers stored in the same record?  This is where I'm confused because it looks like you only have one ContactNumber field but you want to store 2 numbers.  Will the numbers be concatenated together?

Comment: no no, they are being store in sepeate rows. each contact no in a different row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you will only have 2 rows, and you know that there are 2 contact rows in the CompanyContactNo table, you could execute 2 Update statements that would each affect a different row:

```
UPDATE CompanyContactNo
Set ContactNumber=
    (SELECT value FROM @Temp_Table WHERE serial_no = (SELECT MAX(serial_no) FROM @Temp_Table))
WHERE 
    CompanyID=@compID
    AND (CNoId = select MAX(CNoId) FROM CompanyContactNo WHERE CompanyID = @compID)
```

and then for second contact number:

```
UPDATE CompanyContactNo
SET ContactNumber=
        (SELECT value FROM @Temp_Table WHERE serial_no = (SELECT MIN(serial_no) FROM @Temp_Table))
WHERE 
    CompanyID=@compID
    AND (CNoId = select MIN(CNoId) FROM CompanyContactNo WHERE CompanyID = @compID)
```

Comment: Thank u i was still stuck at the problem so i left it and moved on to other part of application ... i 'll try this thing soon